# how to set up composer package with packagist

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I am trying to set up a composer package but i cannot seem to get it to load when i try it from a new project

my package is here https://github.com/shorif2000/pagination and the packgist is here https://packagist.org/packages/shorif2000/pagination

in a new project i have

```
{
    "name": "ec2-user/pagination",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "shorif2000",
            "email": "shorif2000@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "shorif2000/pagination": "dev-master"
    },
    "minimum-stability" : "dev"
}

$ cat index.php
<?php

require './vendor/autoload.php';

use Pagination\Paginator;

$totalItems = 1000;
$itemsPerPage = 50;
$currentPage = 8;
$urlPattern = '/foo/page/(:num)';

$paginator = new Paginator($totalItems, $itemsPerPage, $currentPage, $urlPattern);

?>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- The default, built-in template supports the Twitter Bootstrap pagination styles. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <?php
      // Example of rendering the pagination control with the built-in template.
      // See below for information about using other templates or custom rendering.

      echo $paginator;
    ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

it fails with error 
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Pagination\Paginator' not found in /opt/pagination/index.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/pagination/index.php on line 12`. I tried `use shorif2000\Pagination\Paginator;` which gave same error as well

Comment: What happens when you try and load it using composer? If it can't load, it will throw an error.

Comment: not sure what you mean. i can install it via `composer require shorif2000/pagination`

Comment: The namespace in the package (`Pagination`) doesn't match the namespace you're using in the posted code (`shorif2000\Pagination`)

Comment: what should it be?

Comment: You made the package so surly you know what namespace has?

Comment: i set it to `Pagination`. In the package composer file `"autoload" : {
  "psr-0" : {
   "Pagination" : "src/"
  }
 },` And `Paginator` is under `src`

Comment: You should revert the edits you made to the question. If you update the code you had, the question and answer won't make any sense for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's more than one issue here.

#### composer.json (package)

In your composer file (for the Pagination library), change `PSR-0` to `PSR-4`. `PSR-0` is an old format that was deprecated around 5 years ago (2014).

[Read more about PSR-4 here](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

You should also always end the namespace with `\\`. So the package should be:

```
"autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "Pagination\\" : "src/"
    }
},
```

[Read more about composer autoload here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4)

#### Namespaces

Since you're namespace is `Pagination\`, that's the namespace you should use in the code that uses it.

So if you have a class with:

```
namespace Pagination;

class Pagination {
    ...
}
```

then your `use` statement should simply be:

```
use Pagination\Pagination;
```

[Read more about PHP namespaces here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

The `shorif2000` is the vendor name (which is only for composer to be able to group packages on vendor name and to remove the risk of different packages overwriting each other.

[Read more about composer vendor name here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#name)